Transmit vs Submit in relation to posting to online service or website
I'm writing Terms of Service which shall govern the use of a website.
Users of the website might be allowed to post content (digital assets) to the website.
I'm not sure how should I refer to their action of posting of content.
Do they "Transmit", "Submit", or "Post" the content to the website?
Which of these three terms is the most appropriate to specify in TOS to be proper English terminology when it comes to users posting content to any website.
If you believe some other terms might me more appropriate please name them as well.
If you believe it depends on context, technology or kind of website then please name additional terms that might be more appropriate to same.

I’m voting to close this question because this question asks for specific legal advice, which this site cannot give.

I did say if applicable to this community, the rest of my question is valid though, I'm going to edit out that part.

However if they are talking about "posting of content" then the only appropriate verb is "post",

The content is not limited to text, it may be any digital asset such as software, images, sound, videos etc.

But I hope you see the problem with the question.  You say "They are posting" and then ask "Are they posting, submitting or transmitting"?  Your question contains the answer!

Interesting but problem is that I don't fully understand the difference, so I'm seeking some sort of confirmation to my limited understanding.

I've never seen or heard "transmit" being used in relation to sending something via the internet.  In the context of modern technologies, the verb generally refers to broadcasting via radio waves, or perhaps via telegraphy (in the past).

Transmit has the sense of "send".  You transmit data to the website
Post has the sense of "publish". You post data on the website.  The data could be text, images music etc, that's irrelevant.
If you post data on the website, then you would expect it to be accessed by other users of the website.
If you transmit data to the website, then you may expect it to be assessed only by the owners of the website.  When making a purchase online, I might transmit my credit card number to the website, but I certainly would not post my credit card number on a website!  However the verb "send" would be simpler than "transmit" and more correct in most cases.
If you "submit" then you send data for approval or consideration by the website.
Different words, with different meanings.  I can't tell you which one fits your purpose best.

In context, all three words mean pretty much the same thing.
If you are writing a legal document and looking for legal advice, you'd be better to consult a lawyer than some random boobs on a web forum. "But some guy on the Internet said this was legal!" doesn't carry much weight in court.

I don't think "transmit" (broadcast or send out),  "submit" (present for consideration) and post (publish online)  have the same meaning here.

@JamesK "Transmit" means to send. In context, sending the content to their server. "Submit" means to "offer for acceptance or approval". In this case, offering their content for use. "Post" means "to send information to an online resource". Here, they are sending the information to the server. The words are certainly not exact synonyms, but all mean the same thing in this context.

In legal terms theyvmay have different meanings, to do with e.g. whether the content is requested, whether it's to be moderated, who it's sent to, how many copies are sent, etc. Unsolicited and solicited content may well be handled differently. Submit typically means to send in response to some kind of a request, e.g. contents of a form, application for something, submission for approval or rejection. Transmit and send are more similar to each other, although send implies one to one communications, and transmit is often used of broadcast i.e. one to many.

@Jay It seems to me that both Transmit and Post are OK, that is, both terms should be used, while Submit is not applicable.

@metablaster In "normal" usage, "submit" means to prevent something for approval. Like, "Al submitted his application to the university" or "Betty submitted her paper on gravimetrics to a physics journal." But in computer parlance, anytime data is sent to the computer with a form, we refer to this as "submitting" the data. Many forms have a button at the bottom labeled "Submit". In HTML, the language of web pages, a button that sends data to the server is called a "submit button". So in an IT context, the word fits here. If you were speaking of conventional paper documents, probably not.
